# I have credit on a Google Play account. How do I send it to my primary account?

Tags: google-play-store, google

So here's what happened:

I got a $25 Google Play card. I tried to redeem it on my account, but I got an error due to my country. I used VPN. It still didn't work. Trying to solve the problem, I went into my secondary account, and I wanted to see if it would work, but I would cancel it before it got redeemed. But, it turns out I redeemed it on my secondary account.

So how can I transfer the credits? Can I?

Comment: As far as I am aware you can't.

Answer (score 4):

It's not supported, but you may be able to make use of those credit using [Google Family Account](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7007852).

There is 2 things you have to do:

1. Add your secondary account as [family
   member](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6286986?hl=en)
2. Buy apps using secondary account that **supports** [image: family] family sharing.

After that your primary account will be able use that purchased app for free.